# Seperate items by 3 in for loop

Tags: c++

I want to display `<row></row>` for each of 3 items in loop, I am having issue with this.

Expected output:

[image: screenshot]

I am getting this now for 3,6,9.. items

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding=\"ISO-8859-1"\?>
<results>
  <row>
    <field>1</field>
    <field>2</field>
    <field>3</field>
  </row>
  <row>
    <field>4</field>
    <field>5</field>
    <field>6</field>
  </row>
  <row>
</results>
```

What am I doing wrong with my loop?

```cpp
                   int counter = 0;

            cout << R"(<?xml version="1.0"encoding=\"ISO-8859-1"\?>)" << endl;
            cout << R"(<results>)" << endl;
            cout << R"(  <row>)" << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << R"(    <field>)" << items[i] << R"(</field>)" << endl;
                counter++;
                if (counter == 3)
                {
                    cout << R"(  </row>)" << endl;
                    counter = 0;
                    cout << R"(  <row>)" << endl;
                }
                if (i == items.size() - 1 && stoi(items[i]) % 3 != 0)
                {
                    cout << R"(  </row>)" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << R"(</results>)" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `<row>` appears ***before which line***?

Comment: When you close a row with `cout << R"(  </row>)" << endl;` and it's not the last element you have to open a new row with `cout << R"(  <row>)" << endl;`.

Comment: I've edited my original post, it works fine for every input that is not divisible by 3, but when I input like 6 items, then at the end it adds extra `</row>` that it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good trick with trailing delimiters I learn is to put them AT THE START OF THE LOOP. Pseudocode, that you will use many times in your life:

```
array<x> someValues;

endDelimiter = ",";
for(each value of values) {
  if(NOT firstIteration) 
    print(endDelimiter);

  print(value);
}
```

In your case, you also have a delimiter at the start. If you put the `</row>` at the start of the loop, you can be sure that you have one row to close after the loop terminates, so do it like this:

```
cout << R"(<?xml version="1.0"encoding=\"ISO-8859-1"\?>)" << endl;
cout << R"(<results>)" << endl;
cout << R"(  <row>)" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
{
  // Not the first iteration and 3*x items were printed already
  if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
  {
    cout << "  </row>\n  <row>\n";
  }
  cout << R"(    <field>)" << items[i] << R"(</field>)" << endl;
}
// close the row, if there is no items you still get <row></row>, which is valid XML
cout << R"(  </row>)" << endl;
cout << R"(</results>)" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate both cases, instead of doing it all inside the loop.

1. When you print `</row>` inside the loop. Here you want to do it once every three items, so check `i+1 % 3 == 0`
2. When you print `</row>` in the end. Here you only want to do it after the loop, when the item number is not a multiple of three and therefore its case has not been covered inside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
{
   cout << R"(    <field>)" << items[i] << R"(</field>)" << endl;
   if (i+1 % 3 == 0)
   {
     cout << R"(  </row>)" << endl;
   }
}
if(items.size() % 3 != 0){
  cout << R"(  </row>)" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `</row>` output in your code. The logic is simpler if you keep the first iteration and the final output seperated from the iteration. Then inside the loop you need not distinguish several cases, but its always the same: every 3rd iteration you print the closing and openening tag. Because inside the loop I don't want to check whether the opening tag is needed, the tags are printed before the items and the final closing tag outside of the loop:

```
#include <iostream>


void foo(int num_items) {
    std::cout << "<row>\n";
    std::cout << "<item>0</item>\n";

    for (int i = 1; i < num_items; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0){ std::cout << "</row>\n<row>\n"; }
        std::cout << "<item>" << i << "<\item>\n";
    }
    std::cout << "</row>\n";
}

int main() {
    foo(1);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    foo(3);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    foo(5);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    foo(9);
}
```